# Generate SQL of view to new Query - Teradata

Tags: teradata

When i generate SQL querys from views, i would want them to be created in a new query instead of overwriting the active one. Is that an option somewhere?

[image: Generate SQL of view]

Comment: This is a feature of whatever client you are using. What client is this?

Comment: Teradata SQL Assistant 16.20

Comment: Maybe Teradata Studio is a superior option?

Comment: Tools > Options > General > Allow multiple queries per connection.  That pops the query from generate SQL into a new tab for me.

Comment: Wierd, it does not for me. Maybe i have some other option interfering, or a wierd version of teradata.